# Coin change problem comparison of top-down approaches

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I'm working on LeetCode 322: Coin Change.

> You are given an integer array coins representing coins of different
> denominations and an integer amount representing a total amount of
> money.
>
> Return the fewest number of coins that you need to make up that
> amount. If that amount of money cannot be made up by any combination
> of the coins, return -1.
>
> You may assume that you have an infinite number of each kind of coin.
>
> Example:
>
> Input: coins = [1,2,5], amount = 11
>
> Output: 3
>
> Explanation: 11 = 5 + 5 + 1

I choose a top-down approach where at each iteration I choose a coin whose denomination is not greater than the remaining amount. Sounds easy, right?

The following code passes all test cases.

```
import sys
import functools

class Solution:
    def coinChange(self, coins: List[int], amount: int) -> int:
        @functools.cache   
        def _loop(remaining: int) -> int:
            if remaining == 0:
                return 0
            y = sys.maxsize
            for coin in filter(lambda x: x <= remaining, coins):
                y = min(y, _loop(remaining - coin))

            return (y + 1) if y < sys.maxsize else y
        
        num_coins = _loop(amount)
        return num_coins if num_coins < sys.maxsize else -1
```

But this one doesn't.

```
import sys
class Solution:
    def coinChange(self, coins: List[int], amount: int) -> int:
        num_coins = self._loop(coins, amount, 0, {})
        return num_coins if num_coins < sys.maxsize else -1
    
    def _loop(self, coins: Sequence[int], remaining: int, count: int, memo: MutableMapping[int, int]) -> int:
        if remaining == 0:
            return count
        if remaining not in memo:
            y = sys.maxsize
            for coin in filter(lambda x: x <= remaining, coins):
                y = min(y, self._loop(coins, remaining - coin, count + 1, memo))
            memo[remaining] = y

        return memo[remaining]
```

The only difference between the two solutions is that in the former, `1` is added to the result after the `for` loop (because one coin has been used), and in the latter, `1` is added to the parameter to the recursive call.

What is the bug in the second solution that I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the way you are using `memo`, `memo[x]` is meant to contain the minimum number of coins needed to total `x` cents. However, this is not what is happening.

Let's look at the recursion stack:

```
remaining = 4, count = 0, y = maxsize, take coin 1:
    remaining = 3, count = 1, y = maxsize, take coin 1:
        remaining = 2, count = 2, y = maxsize, take coin 1:
            remaining = 1, count = 3, y = maxsize, take coin 1:
                remaining = 0, count = 4, RETURN 4
            y = 4, memo[1] = 4, RETURN 4
        remaining = 2, count = 2, y = 4, take coin 2:
            remaining = 0, count = 3, RETURN 3
        y = 3, memo[2] = 3, RETURN 3
    remaining = 3, count = 1, y = 3, take coin 2:
        remaining = 1, count = 2, memo[1] exists, RETURN 4
    y = 3, memo[3] = 3, RETURN 3
remaining = 4, count = 0, y = 3, take coin 2:
    remaining = 2, count = 1, memo[2] exists, RETURN 3
y = 3, memo[4] = 3, RETURN 3
```

See the problem? `memo` doesn't have the right values in them. `memo[1]` should be 1, but instead the code is setting it to 4. Similarly, `memo[3]` should be 2, but instead the code is setting it to 3.

To use a `memo` array like you're using, it would be much easier to work from the bottom-up: start with a base condition (`memo[0] = 0`), and calculate the values of `memo[1], memo[2], ... memo[amount]` based on the previously calculated values.

Comment: There's no need to change the code to bottom-up, see my answer. I'll accept yours since you found the bug that I didn't.

Answer (score 1):

OP here: For the record, here's the working code after fixing the bug Tejas Narayan pointed out.

```
import sys
class Solution:
    def coinChange(self, coins: List[int], amount: int) -> int:
        num_coins = self._loop(coins, amount, 0, {})
        return num_coins if num_coins < sys.maxsize else -1
    
    def _loop(self, coins: Sequence[int], remaining: int, count: int, memo: MutableMapping[int, int]) -> int:
        if remaining == 0:
            return count
        if remaining not in memo:
            y = sys.maxsize
            for coin in filter(lambda x: x <= remaining, coins):
                y = min(y, self._loop(coins, remaining - coin, 1, memo))

            memo[remaining] = (y + count) if y < sys.maxsize else y

        return memo[remaining]
```

The fix is reset `count` to `1` for each recursive call.

Comment: Nice! Glad you could fix the top-down approach without having to rewrite it completely.